# Why is FindRoot initial value far from the specified one?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am trying to numerically find the root of a function that looks a bit like: `1/x -  (SchurDecomposition[A[x]][[2]])[[1]]`, where `A` is some matrix using the syntax

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x,3}],
```

where

```
f[x_?NumericQ] = 1/x - (SchurDecomposition[A[x]][[2]])[[1]]
```

However when I monitor the values of x evaluated using the option `StepMonitor :> Print[x]`, the first value that appears is far away (e.g. 6) from my specified start point (i.e. 3). Does anybody understand why it is doing this? This is an issue since the value being used (in my example 6) lies far away from the attractor basin of the function and hence `FindRoot` is giving me a wrong result. The initial starting value (in my example 3) lies very close to the root as I can see by plotting the function. In practice my numbers are a bit different and the function to calculate the matrix `A` quite complicated, however these have been extensively verified and I am sure they are working correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please try to format your code, jut indent the code lines with 4 spaces. It will make it easier to read and more likely that people will help you.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I have always suspected that `FindRoot` does what any good general-purpose root finder will do: it begins by attempting to bracket a root, any root.  (One method is to search to the left and right of a starting point, doubling the step size at each stage, until the function attains values of opposite signs.) You can control this by specifying a bracket yourself via the option `Method -> "Brent"`: see the help page.

Comment: You could constrain the search range using `FindRoot[lhs==rhs,{x,Subscript[x, start],Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]}]` searches for a solution, stopping the search if `x` ever gets outside the range `Subscript[x, min]` to `Subscript[x, max]`.

Comment: What is `3 - f[3]/f'[3]` (the first step in Newton's Method)?  Without `A` no one can really test your code.

Comment: Hi Michael. A good question. I should perhaps first point out that use of EvaluationMonitor instead of StepMonitor shows that the start value is indeed the correct value, however, coming back to your question, the second value given by `3 - f[3]/f'[3]` is very strangely not the same as the second value of x used (i.e. `3 - f[3]/f'[3]` is not 6!)

Comment: The issue with bracketing the root is that `x` is actually a complex variable and `f[x]` is a complex function. The Brent method however requires real limits. The general approach seems to work (for example if I change to considering the second eigenvalue of the matrix `A`) the algorithm converges and finds the root correctly! I guess there is something pathological going on with the first root, however, it's not obvious to me what that is by looking at the landscape of `Abs[f[x]]` near the root.

Comment: For what it's worth I have managed to get this work, albeit it with a workaround. Essentially I first define an interpolating function for the `SchurDecomposition` term and then use this in the definition of `f[x]` instead.